# How to get the last octet of an IP address into 3 separate ints?

Tags: arduino, integer, ip

I need to get the last octet of an IP address into 3 separate `int`s to control a MAX7219.

I know the octet is an `uint8_t`

Using `IPAddress ip = Wifi.localIP();`, say my ip[3] was 148, I need:
int b1 = 1
int b2 = 4
int b3 = 8
but say ip[3] was only 8, then  b1 and b2 have to be 0.

Comment: Why do you need to get the octet into 3 separate integers? What are you doing with those integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that came to mind; there are probably more elegant ways to do this, but it works:

```cpp
b3 = ip[3] % 10;
b2 = ((ip[3] % 100) - b3) / 10;
b1 = (ip[3] - (10 * b2) - b3) / 100;
```

I don't know why you would need separate integers, though.

Answer (score 0):

final function; note no_green is the binary array with led bits

```
void showIP()
{
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  b3 = ip[3] % 10;
  b2 = ((ip[3] % 100) - b3) / 10;
  b1 = (ip[3] - (10 * b2) - b3) / 100;

  // write bits to MAX7219  
  lc.setRow( 0, 6, byte( no_green[ b1] )); // hr leds position
  lc.setRow( 0, 3, byte( no_green[ b2] )); // min leds position 
  lc.setRow( 0, 0, byte( no_green[ b3] )); // sec leds position
  delay(6000);
}
```